# How to send path for changeable object in JavaScript (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to create function which takes object and path inside of this object. The trickiest part is that object will be changed, it means that I can't just get new object...

```
myFunction = (obj, path) => {
   obj[path] = ...
};
```

Right now I send array and it look like this:

```
// path = ['findSupplierById', 'products', 'data']
myFunction = (obj, path) => {
   obj[path[0]][path[1]][path[2]] = ...
};
```

But it is ugly solution because I can have not three array elements.

Comment: something like [_.set()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) might work for you if you don't mind including a third party package. Can be used `_.set(obj, 'findSupplierById.products.data', newValue);`

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/) as Jacob recommended or pure javascript as follows:

```js
myFunction = (obj, path, newVal) => {
  var o = obj;
  const len = path.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len-1; i++) {
    const p = path[i]
    if (!o[p]) o[p] = {}
    o = o[p]
  }
  o[path[len-1]] = newVal
};

const output = {}
myFunction(output, ["a", "b"], "val1")
myFunction(output, ["a", "c"], "val2")
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you friend, but I like more option with lodash set

Comment: Depends on the `path` type. my answer is just based on if `path` is array.